# GRAILS- Image corrupt or truncated

Tags: image, hibernate, grails, blob, truncated

im getting this error "image corrupt or truncated" on FF console when I try to display an image stored in my database. I´m using Grails and Hibernate.
I just want to display a user´s profile picture in my gsp page.

My domain class User has an attribute photo defined as byte[]

```
public class User {

private String userId;
private byte[] photo;
.
.
.
```

The user.hbm.xml mapping is :

```
< property name="photo" type="binary" column="PHOTO" not-null="false" />
```

This collumn is a BLOB on DB.

My gsp:

```
< div id="user-view-thumbnail-container">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Photo Upload</legend>
      <g:form action="uploadPhoto" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="photo">Photo</label>
        <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" />
        <input type="submit" class="buttons" value="Upload" />
      </g:form>
    </fieldset>
  <g:if test="${user.photo}">
    <img alt="User Photo"  src="${createLink(controller:'profile', action:'profile_image', id:user.userId)}" />
  </g:if>
</div>
```

ProfileController:

```
def uploadPhoto = {       
    def user = userService.getUser(authenticateService.principal()) 
    def f = request.getFile('photo')

    user.setPhoto(f.getBytes())

    if (!user.save()) {
        //doesn´t matter now
        return;
    }

    redirect(action: 'index', model:[user: user])
}

def profile_image = {
    def user = userService.getUser(params.id)

    if (!user) {
        response.sendError(404)
        return;
    }
    response.setContentType(user.photo.contentType())//'image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif'
    response.setContentLength(user.photo.size())
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    out.write(user.photo);
    out.close();
}
```

FYI: The picture is saved on DB correctly, I can see it, but I can´t show it on my gsp.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot guys,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use blob type in the mapping :).

Comment: Please add such type of suggestions in comments.